# MapReduce Spark data processing with rdd (scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mapreduce, rdd

I have a big data and i want to use mapRuduce on this data and i don't find anything for this task. (Language:Scala)

The data for this process is:

```
Y,20,01
G,18,40
J,19,10
D,50,10
R,20,01
Z,18,40
T,19,10
Q,50,10
... (2.000+)
```

For all this data i want to load on the maps: (e.g)

```
Y,20,01
G,18,40
J,19,10     MAP 1
D,50,10
---------------------
R,20,01
Z,18,40     MAP 2
T,19,10
Q,50,10
... (2.000+)
```

At all maps, locally i want to find the minimum columns.

After all maps send on the reduce the locally datas and the reduce find the global minimum columns.

Can you help me? 
How will I do it?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to read this data into multiple partitions and call some function on each partition rather than iterating over each element.

Let's consider you want to find the max for each of the given partition.

You can either use `mapPartitions` or `mapPartitionsWithIndex` both of which will run for each of the partitions.

`mapPartitions` will take in an input which will be an iterator and `mapPartitionsWithIndex` should accept 2 parameters namely `index` and `iterator`.

Let's define a function which gets the maximum for a given iterator.

```
//Function to find the max for an iterator and return back an iterator with only the max element
def findMax(numbers :Iterator[Int]) : Iterator[Int] = {
  val max = numbers.max;
  Iterator(max)
}
findMax(Iterator(7,8,9,2,3)).next
//9: Int
```

Let's create an rdd having 2 partitions and print out the elements of each partition.

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(1 to 30, 2)

val mapped = rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex{ (index, iterator) => { 
  val myList = iterator.toList
  val item = Map(index -> myList)
  item.iterator
  }
}

mapped.collect().foreach(println)
/*
(0,List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15))
(1,List(16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30))
*/
```

Now, we can see there are 2 partitions - `0` and `1`.

Next, we'll find the max for each of the partition by using our `findMax` function defined above.

```
val maxByPartitions = rdd.mapPartitions(findMax).collect()
maxByPartitions: Array[Int] = Array(15, 30)
```